# Mask not applying to gameobjects in UI layer

Tags: unity

I have a bunch of item slots in my scroll view.

The item slots contain 3d objects, but they are all set to use the UI layer.

My problem is that they are not being masked the same as the 2D elements are.

See this example:

[image]

Notice how the 3D items in the scroll view are overflowing, but the 3D item slot panels are not.

Like I said, I put everything in the UI layer. I'm not sure how to fix this. Is there a simple fix for this?

Comment: The UI layer just sets a rendering/sorting order, it doesn't replace the shader with one that's masking-aware (which native UI objects use by default). [You can write your own shader that clips 3D geometry to a specific volume](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/139757/39518) if you need.