# How to create 3D area mask?

Tags: unity, c#

I have two cubes, one parent and one child. I want to use the parent's cube mesh as a mask for the child cube. I want to make visible only the part of the child cube that it is inside the parent cube.

I can easily achieve this effect with 2D sprites using the Sprite Mask, but I can't find a way to do it for 3D areas or 3D objects.

What I have:

[image: What I have]

What I want:

[image: What I want]

Comment: What should we see if we look at the cut-off side of the small cube? [It's reasonably easy to just leave it as an open hole](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/139748/39518), but capping it off can be significantly trickier.

Comment: I don't really care about the hole, but it would look better without it.

Answer (score 0):

In 3d editing it is called a Boolean Operation and not a mask.

The operation you are talking about is an Intersection.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.probuilder@4.0/manual/boolean.html

You can use this library:

https://github.com/karl-/pb_CSG

It should work with the cubes fine.

Comment: Recomputing the mesh with CSG might be strictly more work than just clipping the unwanted portion in the shader.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I didn't clarify is that I want it to change in real time while the child cube moves in space in and out of the parent cube. I have used Boolean in the past for 3D model modifications but not sure it will be optimal in this case.

Comment: @user2975038 I think that using a boolean operation should be perfectly ok since it seems like you are planning to use cubes? This is a quick operation and spending unneeded time optimizing this in advance might waste the more important resource -> your time.