# Projector screen effect in Unity

Tags: unity, animation

I would like to make a pull-down projector screen like this:
[image]

I want to animate the screen coming down from the roller at the top. I have a projector model already made, which has a cylinder for the top roller, a thin cube for the white screen, and a plane with a render texture on it for the content being displayed. The plane and cube are in a group.

Is there some way I could make it animate in from the top, as if it was being pulled down, like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8umbn5EYEGI&t=8s)? I would prefer if however this was done without stretching or squashing the image. Keep in mind I'm not too experienced with Unity.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you could just start the screen "above" the tube, and animate it sliding straight down, with a mask/plane [clipping out the parts that are above the tube so they don't render](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/139748/39518). Have you tried anything like that?

Comment: I haven't, but what I want is for the textured plane to appear from the top down. But is there a way to achieve this without shaders?

Comment: I'd say shaders are the way to go. You might be able to hack around it with depth buffer tricks, but that's more complicated and less flexible, and can cause conflicts with other content in the scene. Making the top of the projection appear before the bottom is trivial — there's a built-in projector component that does this already.

Comment: If you've solved your problem (which seems likely from your [later post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/202918/39518)), remember to post your solution as an Answer below, to help other developers struggling with similar effects.