# Render only part of mesh that is intersected into inother Mesh in Unity

Tags: unity, shaders, shaderlab

How can i make ZTest only happen inside a object not behind it?
my shader is simple unlit with two pass one is `ZTest Greater` as red one and one is `ZTest Less` which is blue one.

How i can I achieve the right side result?
[image: ResultIhaveandWant]

Here is my current simple shader code :

```
Shader "Unlit/ShaderX"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 100
        Pass
        {
            ZTest Greater
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            // make fog work
            #pragma multi_compile_fog

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                UNITY_FOG_COORDS(1)
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                UNITY_TRANSFER_FOG(o,o.vertex);
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                // sample the texture
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                // apply fog
                UNITY_APPLY_FOG(i.fogCoord, col);
                return float4(1,0,0,1);
            }
            ENDCG
        }

        Pass
        {
            ZTest Less
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            // make fog work
            #pragma multi_compile_fog

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                UNITY_FOG_COORDS(1)
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                UNITY_TRANSFER_FOG(o,o.vertex);
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                // sample the texture
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                // apply fog
                UNITY_APPLY_FOG(i.fogCoord, col);
                return float4(0,0,1,1);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

A unity staff told me this soultion :

> 1. Render the boxes
> 2. Render the sphere back faces with ztest and write into the stencil buffer : the stencil has now a mask of the sphere but box pixels are missing
> 3. Render the sphere front faces with ztest again and invert the values of the stencil bit: the mask should now be only where the box is intersecting the sphere
> 4. Render the "inside" pass of the box

I have no idea how to do this within shader

Comment: Z-testing is probably not the best way to go about this. If you just want to clip to a spherical region, [you could adapt the shader shown here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/139748/39518) to use a radius check instead of a bounding box check.

Comment: Sphere in image can be any mesh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140165/discussion-between-cyclone-and-dmgregory).