# Unity Particles that only show up inside of a rectangular GameObject

Tags: unity, particles

It's easy enough to use the Unity Particle System to generate snow that falls from the top of a rectangle.

But how do I make snow only fall *inside* the rectangle?  As in, once the snow hits the bottom of the rectangle, I'd like for it to disappear.

The curveball here is that the width of the rectangle can be dynamically resized at times, and I'd want the entire rectangle to always be snowing.

Comment: Have you considered using a shader that clips out snow that leaves the bounding box, [similar to the one shown here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/139748/39518)? (You can ignore the vertex abort trick for your case)

Comment: @DMGregory Would a shader be performant?  I'm looking for a performant solution, in case I end up porting to mobile...

Comment: The best way to answer that question is to profile it. There are enough variables in play here that any answer I give you could be inaccurate for your specific use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a **Box Collider** to define the volume where particles are drawn and tell the **Particle System** to destroy particles lying outside it.

The **Particle System** features the [*Triggers* module](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PartSysTriggersModule.html) that lets you define particle behaviour when they interact with **Colliders** in the Scene. You can use it to destroy particles when they move outside a **Collider** of choice (I suggest a **Box Collider** since you are generating particles from a rectangle):

1. Add a **Box Collider** Component to the **Particle System** GameObject.

   - Alternatively: create a Box GameObject as a child of the **Particle System** GameObject. (Parenting GameObjects allows you to move the System around the Scene.)
2. In the **Particle System**, enable the *Triggers* module.
3. Add a new trigger.
4. Drag and drop the **Box Collider** Component onto the trigger empty slot.

   - Alternatively: drag and drop the GameObject owning the **Box Collider** from the Hierarchy (be it a child GameObject or the **Particle System** GameObject itself).
5. Set the *Outside* trigger condition to "Kill" and the remaining conditions to "Ignore".

You can now define a dedicated shape for *generating* particles and a different one for *containing* them. In your case, you may want to place the rectangle (**Particle System**'s *Shape* module) so that it overlaps the top face of your **Box Collider**.

Here's a quick snapshot from the Inspector:

[image]

---

EDIT: If you want to resize the container volume without manually adjusting the shapes' position, you can use an [Editor script](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor.html) to automatically update the emission shape's position based on the container volume size.

Comment: Thank you, this is incredible!  I got everything working, except the particles aren't being destroyed when they move "Outside" my collider.  I will keep playing with it and report back...

Comment: Oh I see, my collider was configured to be Used By Composite... once I turned that off, then it was easy to kill snowflakes exiting the collider!  I will add a new collider on the parent object and try it that way!

Comment: Thank you thank you, this works perfectly!